# Join two bytes in BASCOM-AVR

Tags: basic, bascom

How can I join two bytes to make an 16-bit int variable in BASCOM-AVR?

Comment: What implementation of BASIC are you using?

Comment: To move 2 bytes to a word try: **Word1 = Byte1 * &H100 + Byte2**

Comment: I'm using BASCOM-AVR.(visual basic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this in BASCOM index:

```
varn = MAKEINT(LSB , MSB)
```

The equivalent code is:

```
varn = (256 * MSB) + LSB
```

- Varn: Variable that will be assigned with the converted value.
- LSB: Variable or constant with the LS Byte.
- MSB: Variable or constant with the MS Byte.

For example:

```
varn = MAKEINT(&B00100010,&B11101101)
```

The result is `&B1110110100100010`.

Answer (score 2):

### PARTIAL ANSWER:

#### Subquestion 1

If one byte is stored in the variable `BYTE1` and the other is stored in the variable `BYTE2`, you can merge them into `WORD1` in many BASICS with `WORD1 = BYTE1: WORD1 = (WORD1 SHL 8) OR BYTE2`. This makes `BYTE1` into the high-order bits of `WORD1`, and `BYTE2` into the low-order bits.

#### Subquestion 2

If you want to mask (or select) specific bits of a word, use the `AND` operator, summing up the bit values of the bits of interest - for example, if you want to select the first and third bits (counting the first bit as the LSB of the word) of the variable `FLAGS`, you would look at the value of `FLAGS AND 5` - 5 is binary `0000000000000101`, so you are guaranteeing that all bits in the result will be 0 except for the first and third, which will carry whatever value they are showing in `FLAGS` (this is 'bitwise AND').

Comment: QB does not have a SHL keyword!

Comment: @eoredson - I would have sworn it did; I do remember BASICs that had that keyword. If `SHL` isn't available then replace `(WORD1 SHL 8) OR BYTE2` with `(WORD1 * 256) OR BYTE2`.

Comment: It does not. That's why I added the SHL/SHR functions in the code below here:

Answer (score 1):

Function to shift-left/right binary:

```
Byte1# = 255
PRINT HEX$(Byte1#)
Byte1# = SHL(Byte1#, 8) ' shift-left 8 bits
PRINT HEX$(Byte1#)
END
' function to shift-left binary bits
FUNCTION SHL (V#, X)
    SHL = V# * 2 ^ X
END FUNCTION
' function to shift-right binary bits
FUNCTION SHR (V#, X)
    SHR = V# / 2 ^ X
END FUNCTION
```